# How can I limit the number of comments per registered user per day?

Tags: comments, limit, comments-template

I found this code on WPSE:

```
global $current_user, $post;
$args = array( 'user_id' => $current_user->ID, 'post_id' => $post->ID );
$usercomment = get_comments( $args );
if ( 1 <= count( $usercomment ) ) {
    echo 'disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

<sup>Note: It seems to limit the number of comments per post per user.</sup>

I want to limit the number of comments per registered user per day.

I would like to be able to change the amount of comments allowed per day in the code, please.

---

If someone could help me with the correct code it would be very much appreciated. Also where would I put this code in the comments.php file?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Chad, have you put this code in your comments template?

Comment: No I have not because its not what I was looking for its was on the tright track though.  Thanks Kaiser.

Comment: Looks like a possible duplicate http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/146032/user-can-post-only-one-comment-per-day-on-one-page

Answer (score 2):

You could pull all of the comments by current user and loop over them to see how may where today or you can create a custom sql Query to select just the count of comments for the last 24 hours, something like this:

```
global $wpdb,$current_user;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM wp_comments 
    WHERE comment_author = '%s'
    AND comment_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);"
    ,$current_user);
$count = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Bainternet.  DO I just need to put this into my comments.php file then?  Not sure where to put this code.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the working version, I referred the technique by @Bainternet to get it done. Just replace `<?php comment_form(); ?>` with this code

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb,$current_user;
    $limit = 5; //this is limit per day per user
    $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM wp_comments 
        WHERE comment_author = '%s'
        AND comment_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);"
        ,$current_user->user_login) );

    if($comment_count < $limit) {
        comment_form();
    }   
    else {
        echo 'exceeded comments limit - '.$limit;
    }
?>
```

<sup>-- Tested on Wordpress 3.4.1 with TwentyTen theme installed on_</sup>

#### Note -

> - Simply Hides the comment form from users with more than 5 comment for that given day *`Regardless of comment status`*
> - This will show comment form to unregistered users unless we disable it from - *`Discussion Settings`*