# User can post only one comment per day on one page

Tags: comments

This code count comments per day on all pages. I want that will count only on one page for 1 day.  So my case: on a page with an ID of `1`, a user can comment with out any limit, but  on a page with an ID of `2`, the same user can only comment once per day.

```
<?php 
global $wpdb,$current_user;
$limit = 5; //this is limit per day per user
$comment_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM wp_comments 
    WHERE comment_author = '%s'
        AND comment_date >= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY );",
        $current_user->user_login
) );

if ( $comment_count < $limit ) {
    comment_form();
}   
else {
    echo 'exceeded comments limit - '.$limit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Limiting comments per day and per user is already built into your current query. The only thing missing is a check for the post ID. Here's a pretty convenient function/template tag:

```
/**
 * @param int $limit 
 * @param int $time
 * @param int $ids 
 */
function is_user_limit_reached( $limit = 5, $time = 1, $ids = array() )
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Cast to array
    ! is_array( $limited ) AND $limited = array( $limited );

    // Generate SQL clause
    $ids = ! empty( $ids )
        ? sprintf( " and comment_post_ID in (%s)", join( ",", $ids ) )
        : "";

    // Rows: user_id, comment_date, comment_post_ID
    $count = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "select count(*)
        from {$wpdb->comments} 
        where user_id=%d 
            and comment_date >= date_sub( now(), interval %d day )
            %s",
        get_current_user_id(),
        $time,
        $ids
    ) );

    return $count >= $limit;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
if ( is_user_limit_reached(
    10,                      // allowed comments per day
    7,                       // in the last 7 days
    array( 1, 35, 97, 1148 ) // array of post IDs which have a limit
    ) )
{
    echo 'Your limit is already reached. Come back tomorrow';
}
else
{
    comment_form();
}
```

You could as well switch the comment box template tag on/off, etc. The sky is your limit.

Comment: sory but this code not work for me. i test but user can add non limited comment on page. fist code i add in functions.php and the second code in my page template

Comment: @ToniOjsteršek Update your question with your current code. I tested it on the command line and it works flawless. Btw, if it does not work, please untick the check mark for "solution". Thanks.

Comment: `if ( is_user_limit_reached(
    1,                      // allowed comments per day
    7,                       // in the last 7 days
    array( 2944 ) // array of post IDs which have a limit
) )
    return print 'Your limit is already reached. Come back tomorrow';
` this is my code and if i add 0 to  // allowed comments per day i get the "Your limit is already reached. Come back tomorrow" but footer isn't displayed i dont know is some other way

Comment: @ToniOjsteršek Show your complete code in an edit to your question. Comments are no place to add long code. Aside from that, I am 99% sure that your problem is a simple PHP problem - the `return` simply ends the template...